# Can you Force Type Casting in PHP?

Tags: php, php-ini

I have been doing some research online and it appears that the answer to my question is no, but I realize there are times when I might miss something or search for something incorrectly. I know in languages like C++, when a variable is declared it can be declared as int or string. Is it possible to force this in PHP?

For Example:

```
<?php
(int)$var = 5;
?>
```

will be validated and not cause an error in PHP, but:

```
<?php
$var = 5;
?>
```

will cause an error because it was not cast as a type string, int, object, etc...

I know PHP is loosely typed so this may not be an option, however I would like to use it that way I ensure that I sanitize data appropriately and improve readability by letting others know exactly what is going on with the code. I am hoping there is a way to enforce this in the php.ini file or to load it in a script that will always be executed by my program.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: You can create classes that will return a properly type casted variable values. There are no ini directives that make it possible, or any other mechanism.

Comment: Cast variables? Yes. Type hint? Sometimes. Strongly type variables? No.

Comment: PHP was written to give us the ability of writing pages simply and quickly. So whenever you declare a variable, PHP transforms it automatically in the datatype you need.

Comment: I had a feeling that there wasn't going to be, given that's what my original research was showing. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: @Wiggler Jtag: "So whenever you declare a variable, PHP transforms it automatically in the datatype you need" --- that's not entirely correct actually

Comment: @John Conde: "Cast primitive types" - yes. "Cast anything" - no

Comment: @zerkms An important clarification

Comment: @WigglerJtag I know that PHP does that automatically, but it seems to allow for some bad programming habits or to allow things to happen that shouldn't happen, in my opinion.

Comment: @kccoers: if you wanted a language that will not forgive you some "obvious" mistakes - then choosing php was your first mistake :) PS: the type of the data should be generally obvious from the variable name

Comment: @zerkms I agree completely, however the shop that I work for develops applications with PHP, we are starting to move away from it, and is the bulk of our projects, so we were hoping to implement it in a way that is not so forgiving :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is loosely typed and does not require you to declare a variable type when declaring a variable. You can’t change that behavior with a magic `php.ini` directive.

The benefit of having “loose typing” is that it allows for flexibility. It allows you to create dynamic applications without having to worry about the type of the variable – PHP makes this possible by *not* enforcing variable types.

However, if you *must* convert a variable into a particular format, just cast it:

```
$int   = (int) $foo;
$str   = (string) $foo;
$bool  = (bool) $foo;
$float = (float) $foo;
...
```

There are functions to do the same, e.g. [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval), [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval), [`boolval()`](http://php.net/boolval) – all of them do the same task, but a function is very useful when you want to use it as a callback to another function.

Comment: Thank you for this, I know about the benefits of loose typing and I personally don't like them, but I think that comes down to a matter of preference. The main thing I was looking for was ways to force myself and the team I program with to adhere to certain principles without human intervention.

Comment: @kccoers: Well, PHP is loosely-typed and you can't change that. If you feel like PHP's features go against your coding principles, then by all means, do not use it.

Comment: That is something that we are looking into. I know we have a lot more projects that are coming down the line that are sold with PHP, but other platforms are going to be used in the future.